# How can i get in between rows in mysql query

Tags: mysql, doctrine, dql

I want to fetch intermediate rows from by database.

Like for last 10 rows i will use limit :

```
    return Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->select('v.*')
                ->from('Video v')                   
                ->where("v.community_id='$community_id' AND v.user_id='$user_id' AND v.published='$published'")
                ->orderBy('v.id DESC')
                ->limit(10)
                ->execute();
```

but what if i want 110-120 rows?Can anybody tell me about that? how to write this kind of query in doctrine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use offset clause...[chk dis](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/dql-doctrine-query-language:limit-and-offset-clauses)

Comment: Why did you accept your own answer SIX DAYS after you were given the same answer by multiple people?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [offset()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/dql-doctrine-query-language:limit-and-offset-clauses) clause.

Comment: much easier than using the pager

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use a [`Doctrine_Pager`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/utilities:pagination#working-with-pager)

```
$page = 10;
$limit = 10;
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('t.*')
        ->from('SomeTable t')

$pager = new Doctrine_Pager(
    $query,
    $page,
    $limit
);

$rows = $pager->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

For rows 110-120, you want

```
LIMIT 109, 10
```